# Click on bottom tab to prompt a modal using React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Anyone know how to prompt a modal when press on the bottom tab? In React Native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add event listener for `tabPress` and trigger the modal from the event listener. Like this:

```js
const [showModal, setShowModal] = React.useState(false);

React.useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('tabPress', (e) => {
    // Prevent default behavior
    e.preventDefault();
    setShowModal(true);
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, [navigation]);
```

and in your return part:

```js
<Modal
  visible={showModal}
  onRequestClose={() => {
    setShowModal(false);
  }}
>
  {/* Your code */}
</Modal>
```

the `e.preventDefault()` is optional, if you want to prevent `tabPress` to navigate to another screen then to that, otherwise don't use it.

Comment: it works for me, thankyou very much!

Comment: @Shmily, no worries.